# Different values of checksum and hash

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sha1, checksum

I'm sure this questions comes from a lack of understanding between a SHA-1 hash and a SHA-1 checksum. The two terms seem to be interchangeable although I'm assuming it's more a scenario of the two being conflated.

When I run the following on a macOS machine...

`echo -n password | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}'`

...I get a value that is completely different than if I generate a value using `hashlib` in Python3.

What gives here? Thanks!

Comment: In this context checksum and hash and equivalent and interchangeable, and I get the same values for the SHA1 hash of 'password' using your little one-liner above and python3. So you will need to post your python3 code to prove the results are different.

Comment: Turns out it was a typo on my side. Thanks for keeping me honest @PresidentJamesK.Polk